# What can I use to tunnel under a walkway or driveway?

Tags: installation, utilities

I have seen [Walkway Tunnel Kits](http://www.homedepot.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?productId=100127846&storeId=10051&langId=-1&catalogId=10053&cm_sp=BazVoice-_-RLP-_-100127846-_-x) being sold in the US, unfortunately I can't find a similar product in the UK.  Are there alternative products or methods, that can be used when a product like this is not available?

Comment: It appears to simply be a jet nozzle for your hose. Seems that any garden center should have one.

Comment: @DA01, it is more then just a jet nozzle, as it fixes onto a PIPE, a hose is not stiff enough to push on it's own.   However I am thinking of using my power waster inside of a old down pipe to get the same outcome.

Comment: You don't really even need a nozzle, just a pipe thread to hose thread adapter, and some pipe. I've tunnelled under a walk with just a garden hose, no pipe, no nozzle. No direction control, comes out where it wants, but it did get to the other side. Obviously need pipe for longer distances. If you want more water velocity, just drill a hole in an end cap and attach to the pipe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tunneled under a concrete pad using lengths of rigid pipe, a hose, and lots of dedication.

You dig a substantial hole on both sides, then you put the hose in the pipes with a pressure nozzle, then you hammer the pipes through the ground and put them together as you need length.