# How can I run a line under a cement sidewalk

Tags: pvc, cement, porch, underground

What's a good way run a length of 2" PVC underground from one side of the porch to the other. I'd use it as a culvert to route a garden hose in the long term.

The cement step and walk are 4' wide.  The step is 7"x16", or about 3 cubic ft, or about 450 lbs.  The house was built in the early 1940s in SW Washington state.  There is an irregular 1/2" gap between the step and the base of the porch suggesting it is not attached to the porch.

Rather than trench underneath the walk or step, I was thinking of rolling back the 4 ft wide step 90 degrees, digging a trench, laying the PVC, covering the PVC with sand, then rolling the step back.

Or rent a cement saw and cut off 2" of cement walk where it abuts the step and is cracked anyway, lay the hose (no PVC), lay sand, then fit a piece of PT 2x lumber ripped to fit.

What is your suggestion?

[image]

Comment: Related: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/15464/what-can-i-use-to-tunnel-under-a-walkway-or-driveway

Comment: oops, almost a duplicate. ok with me to merge or delete this one

Answer (score 2):

Unless you want to get into concrete repair here and need an excuse, dig a 5-6 foot long pit on one side of the sidewalk, and a 1 foot long pit on the other side. Drop pipe into the 5-6 foot long pit, hammer in. Run a hose up it and flush the dirt out (probably not continuously - it's easy to overdo) and drive some more. When it pops out on the far side you are done. Won't work if you hit a big rock. Cut the turf off neatly so you can patch the hole in the lawn when you are done, or just do it in the flowerbed and put the plants and mulch back.

Comment: Interesting idea.  I do have a 8lb sledge and a 7 ft length of scrap 2" galvy pipe. How can I cut the pipe to length?

Comment: They make a nozzle you can glue onto the end of a piece of pvc pipe (and a hose fitting for the other end) to help with this. I've used it to cross under a 3-4' sidewalk and it worked pretty well, without needing to use galvanized pipe or sledgehammers. It's on the Home Depot website as a "walkway tunnel kit".

Comment: For $5 that might be the way to go. I guess it's not meant as a culvert through which to route a garden hose, but to remain in place as bart of the 'sprinkler' piping?

Comment: Yes. I still have the thing in my garage so I guess I pulled it out and routed a second piece of PVC through the tunnel it left behind.

Comment: i have one of these http://i.imgur.com/HNVjEeV.jpg. I'll try that on a garden hose threaded though some pvc.

Comment: I do almost the same thing but just make a connection to a pice of conduit and water hose. By pushing in and pulling back I have gone over 20' with 3/4. Cut the end off because it gets chewed up a bit on the first inch or 2.

Comment: how far beneath the walk do you suggext?  1-2" or 4-6" or ???

Comment: Ed - do you use metal conduit? do you have any kind of nozzel to concentrate the water stream?